# Does Redis support cross replication between master/slave nodes?

Tags: redis, distributed-system, distributed-caching

Based on Redis documentation, a cluster of two Redis nodes (one Master node and one Slave node) can support replication via the **slaveof** directive.
However, this implies that replication is always performed from Master to Slave.

Assuming we don't use Sentinel, then in case of a failover, the Slave will have the proper data but will still be a Slave node. Thus, as soon as the Master node recovers from failure, data will either be wiped out or be as per the latest snapshot (if RDB/AOF persistence is enabled).

Now, to the question: does Redis support **cross replication** between Master/Slave nodes? If not, is there a way to replicate (no pun intended) such a functionality without using Sentinel?

Comment: What do you mean by cross replication?

Comment: @ [Purushotham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3030146/purushotham-kumar): By cross replication I mean that the Master can replicate its keys to the Slave **and** vice versa.

This is necessary in case two Redis nodes are load balanced via httpd or HAProxy using active/active mode.